# Javascript Object [sorting]

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

If i use integer as a key in javascript object it shorts automatically.

```
var obj = {"z": 100, "x": 75, "d": 116, "c": 15, "10":123, "9":12}
console.log(obj)
```

Output:

```
{9: 12, 10: 123, z: 100, x: 75, d: 116, c: 15}
```

It is not maintaining sequence for integer, It works for alphabetical strings.

**My question is** Why it is so ?  and how to overcome this if i need to manage sequence?

Comment: ECMA-262 does not require Object properties to be sorted in any particular order, therefore the order is implementation dependent and you should **never** rely on it.

Comment: thanks, i just want this answer "It is not possible" :P

Comment: It is possible with a [*Map* object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map-constructor), but not a plain Object (also see [*MDN: Map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)).

Comment: yes but if i use map than i need to use get and set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object key ordering is not guaranteed. See [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order). Use an array of objects to guarantee ordering.

```
var arr = [{"z":100}, {"x":75}, {"d":116}, {"c":15}, {"10":123}, {"9":12}]
```

Comment: Arrays don't guarantee order either, however there are methods to visit the numeric properties in sequence (from low to high or high to low).

Answer (score 1):

Use an array if you want to keep the order. That is one of the way to maintain the order in javascript.

Comment: Arrays aren't ordered either, that's why you should use a *for* loop or similar to visit them in sequence and never a *for..in* loop.

Answer (score 1):

The order of properties in objects are not guaranteed in JavaScript. If you would like something similar to an object that does guarantee order look into the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) Object.

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set('z', 100);
myMap.set('x', 75);
myMap.set('d', 116);
myMap.set('c', 15);
myMap.set('10',113);
myMap.set('9', 12);
```

Order in maps **IS** guaranteed

[image]

Arrays also keep order, yet are not keyed by names, rather by an index.

Comment: Arrays don't "keep order" either, but the numeric keys can be visited in sequence. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the order use "9.0", "10.0" instead of `9 or 10`.

Try with this

```
{"z":100,"x":75,"d":116,"c":15,"10.0":123,"9.0":12}
```

And it is a known issue [issue 164](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164)

Comment: It might be an issue, but it's not a bug in regard to compliance with ECMA-262. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try sort as a map?

I have misunderstood the question before.

```
Object[] obj = new Object[]{"z": 100, "x": 75, "d": 116, "c": 15, "10":123, "9":12};
for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
{
    System.out.print(obj[i].toString() + " ");
}
```

Like

```
Map<String, String> objMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
objMap.put("z", 100); .....
entriesSortedByValues(objMap);
```

Or You can treat it like JSON

```
var arr = [
{name: "z",
 value:100
 }, 
.....];
```

then wrote a function
like

```
funtion sortObj(column)
{
   return function(x,y)
          {
             if(x[column] > y[column])
             {
                return 1;
             }
             elseif(x[column] < y[column]){return -1;}
             else{return 0;}
          }
}

array.sort(sortObj(value));
```

Comment: i don't want sorting i just want to get same order like before

Comment: So, you just want to output the sequence like what is inside the array?

Comment: yes, in the same order as i initialize object.
Currently it changing order

Comment: I have update the code at the top. See whether it works